# exclude expression from regex match

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've gone over the different pages of SO on regex (and the many regex questions related to negate, negation, exclusion, filter out, etc) to find a solution for a regex, without any luck so far.

I have the following list of entries:

```
poliester 6 blanco cod 3 xyz
pol 6 negro cod 3 abc
poliester 6 verde cod 7
pol 6 vde cod 7
pol 4 amarillo cod 3
poliester 3 zapote cod 7
poliester 6 cafe
poliester 6 negro cod 4 jpg
poliester 3 456 verde cod 3
pol 6 blanco cod 2
```

of which I need to get those that contain `pol.* 6 .*` AND either `cod 3`, `cod 7` or those without any mention to `cod 4` or `cod 2`.

The many regexes I've tried at regex101.com fail either because they retrieve the mention to `cod 4` or `cod 2`, or because they fail to retrieve the `poliester 6 cafe` line.

Below some of the regexes I've tried:

```
pol.* 6 .*(cod [^42])
pol.* 6 .*((?!cod [^42])|cod 3|cod 7).*
pol.* 6 .*((?<!cod [^42])|cod 3|cod 7).*
```

The expected result is:

```
poliester 6 blanco cod 3 xyz
pol 6 negro cod 3 abc
poliester 6 verde cod 7
pol 6 vde cod 7
poliester 6 cafe
```

I'm working out the regex so far (using regex101), and I plan to use it in a R query afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that following does (from description)

```
pol.* 6 (?:(?=.*cod [37])|(?!.*cod [42])).*
```

Note that it may be equivalent to just

```
pol.* 6 (?!.*cod [42]).*
```

which may be improved to reduce backtracking

```
pol[^ ]* 6 (?!.*cod [42]).*
```